# Displaying an opengl program on tightvnc webviewer

Tags: vnc, ubuntu-12.04, tightvnc

I'm using TightVNC, because I want to display an opengl program running on linux on a webpage. When I run the program ubigraph, I get the following error message:

> freeglut (./ubigraph_server): OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':1'

Are there settings to configure or other programs to try to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualGL](http://www.virtualgl.org/) and [TurboVNC](http://www.virtualgl.org/Downloads/TurboVNC) would be the way to go.

Comment: OR as an alternative, X11 forwarding might do the trick.